# Cell formula not being update when inserted with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I insert a formula in a cell using Apps Script, and in this formula there are references to other cells of the same line.

The problem is, my apps script will also insert new lines. And the formula stay unchanged (the references should change since the row index has changed).

How can I do that ?

```
/* This function is called several times and so "A2" only makes sense
at the time I set the formula, after that, it should become "A3" or "A4"
*/
function writeDataLine(dataSheet, date, playerName, idx) {
  var formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(A2;G$2:H;2;FALSE)=C2;1;0)"
  dataSheet.getRange(idx + 2, 4, 1, 1).setFormula(formula);
}
```

(I write in D2, and make ref to A2 and C2)

[edit]
I tried R1C1 notation but get `#ERROR!`

```
function writeDataLine(dataSheet, date, playerName, idx) {
  var formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-3];G2:H;2;FALSE)=R[0]C[-1];1;0)"
  dataSheet.getRange(idx + 2, 4, 1, 1).setFormulaR1C1(formula);
}
```

Comment: Use R1C1 referencing

Comment: tried `var formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-3];G2:H;2;FALSE)=R[0]C[-1];1;0)"` and `setFormulaR1C1` but I get `#ERROR!`

Comment: What `#ERROR!`?

Comment: "Analysis error"

Comment: `G:H` is not RC

Comment: but `G2:H` must a fixed range, how can I express this ?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is you have used a mix of RC and A1notations, while setting formulasR1C1. Without square brackets, `RC` is absolute. So, `R2C7:R1000C8`  can be used for `G2:H1000`.

Regardless, I don't think you'll need a script. I believe what you want is

D2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(VLOOKUP(A2:A100;G$2:H;2;FALSE)=C2:C100;1;0))
```

Alternatively, You can just use [AutoFill](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#autoFill(Range,AutoFillSeries)) method on range D2 without using R1C1.

Comment: I went with the arrayformula. At the beginning I didnt want because I had no first line (first line was filled by my AppsScript). But I finally have old data to migrate and so I can ut my formula by hand)